# SSAS - getting error while importing data from SQL Server

Tags: ssas, ssas-tabular

I am trying to import data into SSAS Tabular and I get the below error every time I enter my current username and password. Can you please confirm what is this error related to as I am new to the SSAS.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Seems like a permissions issue, try running it as administrator

Comment: @Meh - Thank you, I ran Visual Studio in Administrator mode and everything works. Thanks again!